# Get bytes of an image from a package

Tags: image, flutter

In order to get bytes of an image in flutter app one can use:

```
final data = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
```

But, how do you get bytes of an image that is from a package, for example from an **AssetImage** which contains **assetName** and a **package**?

Comment: Are there something that prevent you from getting the bytes with the `rootBundle` when you have the image name/ path?

Comment: It doesn't work for image asset from a package. @Bach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/AssetImage-class.html

> Assets in packages To fetch an asset from a package, the package
> argument must be provided. For instance, suppose the structure above
> is inside a package called my_icons. Then to fetch the image, use:
>
> AssetImage('icons/heart.png', package: 'my_icons') Assets used by the
> package itself should also be fetched using the package argument as
> above.
>
> If the desired asset is specified in the pubspec.yaml of the package,
> it is bundled automatically with the app. In particular, assets used
> by the package itself must be specified in its pubspec.yaml.
>
> A package can also choose to have assets in its 'lib/' folder that are
> not specified in its pubspec.yaml. In this case for those images to be
> bundled, the app has to specify which ones to include. For instance a
> package named fancy_backgrounds could have:
>
> lib/backgrounds/background1.png lib/backgrounds/background2.png
> lib/backgrounds/background3.png To include, say the first image, the
> pubspec.yaml of the app should specify it in the assets section:
>
> assets:
> - packages/fancy_backgrounds/backgrounds/background1.png The lib/ is implied, so it should not be included in the asset path.